# php send email from another domain

Tags: php, email

I am making an application that allows users to send emails of complaint to a leader at my university. I would like them to as much as possible to appear they are coming from the users own email rather than from the website.

I'd use mailto links but I find a lot of people these days don't use outlook... most people use web mail :S

I guess the other option is to use the reply to field so at least the replies end up in the right inbox.

Comment: What is your question?  What have you tried?  What errors have you received?  Have you [googled for information relating to what you're trying to accomplish](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=php+send+email)?

Answer (score 1):

The [send](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function allows you to specify additional headers - this includes `From:` and `Reply-To`.

However, you should make sure your mails are white-listed in the spam detection configuration, because anti-spam tools will (rightfully) mark your mails as spam.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this reliably: A faked sender address is among the #1 signs for spam and is likely to be filtered out.

The best you can do is specify a legit sender address on your server, and give the user's address in the `reply-to` header. In most mail clients, that address will show up as the sender.

Answer (score 0):

As Pekka highlighted, you can set the from address but this is likely to get it specified as spam.

An alternative would be to send the email to the user with instructions for them to forward the mail to the University Leader, a bit roundabout but might do the trick.